# java program that takes a word and randomizes the letters and creates an anagram

Tags: java, substring, charat

I need to create a program that will take a word without spaces, punctuation, and all lowercase, and rearranges the letters randomly. It needs to have substrings or charAt, I cannot use an array since we have not learned them yet. It also hsa to be different everytime, really n! times I think. This is what I have so far-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner kboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter a word that is less than 11 lowercase letters and has no punctuation or spaces: ");       
      String word = kboard.next();
      while(word.length()>1)
      {
            System.out.print(word.charAt(1));
            System.out.print(word.charAt(0));
            word = word.substring(2);
      }
      System.out.println(word);
}
```

This rearranges the words, but it does not do it random every time. I thought I could do something like this, but I think it is messy and doesn't make much sense.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner kboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      String word, pt1 = "", pt2 = "", pt3 = "";
      System.out.println("Enter a word that is less than 11 lowercase letters and has no punctuation or spaces: ");
      word = kboard.nextLine();
      int num1 = 0, num2 = 0, thing = 0;
      while(thing<4)
      {
          thing = thing + 1;
          num1 = (int)(word.length() * Math.random() + 1);
          num2 = (word.length() - (word.length() % num1));
      }
          pt1 = word.substring(num1, num2);
          pt2 = word.substring(num1, num2);
          pt3 = word.substring(num1, num2);
          System.out.print(pt1);
          System.out.print(pt2);
          System.out.print(pt3);
```

So what can I do to randomize the letters?

Comment: Although this task is certainly possible with using arrays, it would be very difficult for a beginner. I suspect you are missing some crucial details about the task description. I suggest to double-check and make sure to include all details.

Comment: The assignment is to take a word that is less than 11 letters, no punctuation, no spaces, and to rearrange the letters randomly. We have just started strings and have not gone into arrays yet. That is all we were told to do. It gave us an example that if the word was abcde it could output as ebadc

Comment: I've provided my solution to your problem as an answer below, but as it is not really related to you question I will also comment. If you are requested to put no more than 11 lowercased letters with no punctuation and spaces, you should check your input for those cases :)
E.g. look at method isLowerCase, isWhiteSpace and so on (in class Character )

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution to all "how do I randomize" a fixed set of elements is: shuffling.

Simply turn your String into a List of Character, to then [shuffle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)) that list.

( creating that list boils down to `new ArrayList<>(yourWord.toCharArray()` ).

Answer (score 1):

GhostCat beat me in a few seconds :)

```
    char[] arr = "abcdefg".toCharArray();
    List<Character> list = new LinkedList<>(); // copy the chars to a list
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        list.add(arr[i]);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(list);  // use to shuffle
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { // copy the shuffled chars back to the array
        arr[i] = list.get(i);
    }
    System.out.println(new String(arr));
```

Comment: I dont know how to use array though, and i cannot use on on this program

Answer (score 1):

This could be implemented very easily using standard libraries,
but it seems you cannot use arrays and lists,
which makes this exercise a bit harder than it needs to be.

You can implement the following algorithm:

- Initialize the output as an empty string
- while the word is not empty

  - Pick a character randomly
  - Append the character to the output
  - Remove the selected character from the word, by replacing word with the part before the index + the part after the index

This can be implemented reasonably efficiently using a `StringBuilder`:

```
String shuffled(Random random, String word) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(word.length());
    StringBuilder rest = new StringBuilder(word);
    while (rest.length() > 0) {
        int index = random.nextInt(rest.length());
        result.append(rest.charAt(index));
        rest.deleteCharAt(index);
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

If you cannot use a `StringBuilder`,
then you can work with strings,
but this will be less efficient,
and normally not recommended in Java.
(Because it involves many string concatenations, which is inefficient.)

```
String shuffled(Random random, String word) {
    String result = "";
    String rest = word;
    while (!rest.isEmpty()) {
        int index = random.nextInt(rest.length());
        result += rest.charAt(index);
        rest = rest.substring(0, index) + rest.substring(index + 1);
    }
    return result;
}
```

You can call this with:

```
String shuffled = shuffled(new Random(), word);
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String test = "onetwothree";
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i=0;i<test.length();i++){
            int randomCharacterPosition = random.nextInt(test.length());
            String start = test.substring(0,randomCharacterPosition);
            String end = test.substring(randomCharacterPosition);
            test = end.concat(start);

        }
        System.out.println(test);
    }
```

Basically you getting a string,  randomly choose a position in string. 
Using this position you dividing input string into two strings and swaping them.

Nothing more than random, substring and concat (which can be replaced with  + operator)